# Ante un error 404, actualizar la página solo una vez en XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría ver si hay alguna forma de implementar un contador o alguna solución que haga que la página se actualice solo una vez después del evento 404.

En la línea 90 del código que compartiré con ustedes al final tengo el problema ya que se forma un bucle con el error 404 y la página se actualiza indefinidamente.

**Línea 90:**
`} else if (this.status === 404) { location.reload(); console.log("Error 404")}`

**Código completo:**

```
this.refreshCover = function (songIt = '', artistIt) {
        // Default cover art
        var urlCoverArt = DEFAULT_COVER_ART;
        
                    
        // URL of proxy for lyrics Api CORS Allow Origin *
        var proxy_URL = PROXYURL;
        
        var itunes_api = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=';

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var coverArt = document.getElementById('currentCoverArt');
            var coverBackground = document.getElementById('bgCover');
            var backgroundDefault = 'img/background.jpg';
            
            
            // Get cover art URL on iTunes API
            if (this.readyState === 4) { 
                
                if (this.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                
                var artworkUrl100 = (data.resultCount) ? data.results[0].artworkUrl100 : urlCoverArt;

                // Se retornar algum dado, alterar a resolução da imagem ou definir a padrão
                urlCoverArt = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? artworkUrl100.replace('100x100bb', '512x512bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt96 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '96x96bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt128 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '128x128bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt192 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '192x192bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt256 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '256x256bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt384 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '384x384bb') : urlCoverArt;

                
                
                coverArt.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + urlCoverArt + ')';
                coverArt.className = 'animated bounceInLeft';
                
                // If song cover art = default cover art change background default              
                if(coverArt.style.backgroundImage == 'url("img/103-logo.png")') {
                    coverBackground.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + backgroundDefault + ')'
                } else  { coverBackground.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + urlCoverArt + ')'
                }
                
                          

                setTimeout(function () {
                    coverArt.className = '';
                }, 2000);
                
                                                                
                if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
                    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
                        title: songIt,
                        artist: artistIt,
                        artwork: [{
                                src: urlCoverArt96,
                                sizes: '96x96',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt128,
                                sizes: '128x128',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt192,
                                sizes: '192x192',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt256,
                                sizes: '256x256',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt384,
                                sizes: '384x384',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt,
                                sizes: '512x512',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            
            } else if (this.status === 404) { location.reload(); console.log("Error 404")}
        }
    }   
        
                
        xhttp.open('GET', proxy_URL + itunes_api + artistIt + ' ' + songIt + '&media=music&limit=1.', true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

Aclaro que el error 404 es un error interno de la API de Itunes, no es porque no se encuentre la caratula solicitada.

En el código ya está prevista la situación de que la API no encuentre la imagen solicitada y funciona perfectamente usando una imagen por defecto.

`// Default cover art var urlCoverArt = DEFAULT_COVER_ART;`

`var artworkUrl100 = (data.resultCount) ? data.results[0].artworkUrl100 : urlCoverArt;`

Cuando la API no encuentra la imagen solicitada devuelve `0` y si la encuentra devuelve `1`, pero siempre en estado 200.

[image: no encuentra imagen]

[image: encuentra imagen]

Error 404:

[image: Error 404 encabezado]
[image: Error 404]

El error 404 se da de forma poco frecuente por otros motivos internos de la API, y ante ese error permanece la imagen de la canción anterior, ni siquiera pone la que he configurado por defecto, pero si refresco la página al menos obtengo la imagen por defecto en ese momento y el usuario no tiene que hacer nada.

No me gustaría que el usuario tuviera que interactuar con la página refrescando su navegador, busco una solución automática desde el front end.

Quizá usando algún contador para que que luego de 1 refresh no lo realice nuevamente.

Se que la solución no es nada fácil desde el front end, pero no creo en los imposibles en informática, si alguien piensa como yo y tiene los conocimientos o la inteligencia de encontrar una solución para este caso le estaría muy agradecido. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajusta la parte del refresh para que no permita mas de uno, puedes guardar una variable local en almacenamiento persistente (localStorage) y hacer lo siguiente:

```
    // tu codigo para el caso normal/exitoso
    // ...
    localStorage.setItem("is_retry",'0'); // reset variable reintentos 
}
else 
if (this.status === 404) { 
     console.log("Error 404"); // console antes del refresh
     if (localStorage.getItem("is_retry")!='1'){
         localStorage.setItem("is_retry",'1'); // marcar reintento
         location.reload(); 
     }else{
         // que hacer si ya se reintentó? mensaje, aviso, etc
     }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución, ya la he subido al servidor, ahora toca esperar que Itunes de el error 404 para comentarte como me fue y para marcar esta respuesta como la mejor. Por ahora van mis +10 por el tiempo que has dedicado a ayudarme. Te mantendré informado.

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección! Edito: Puedes agregar esta solución a mi otro post en inglés, así te ganas los creditos por tu esfuerzo. El otro post está aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63608178/in-the-event-of-a-404-error-refresh-the-page-only-once-in-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Bueno no deseo molestarte en que respondas otro hilo. Me auto respondo y cito los créditos como tuyos. Gracias nuevamente.